# Independence, conditioning, and correlations

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, independence

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Suppose we consider a conditional distribution of $X$ and $Y$ on some event $C$. Is it possible that these conditional distributions are correlated?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An image generated with `Python` function `seaborn.jointplot` [http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html](http://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html), illustrating the answer given by @grand.chat.[image]

EDITED The graph of a joint probability density function of $(X,Y)$ is a surface $z=f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Usually to illustrate such a distribution one displays its contour plot, that is some level lines projected onto the $x-y$ plane.

In our case the joint p.d.f. $f_{X,Y|((X,Y)\in C)}$ is equal to $2$ for $(x,y)\in C$ and zero otherwise. Hence the theoretical contour plot consists in just one contour line (the triangle of vertices $(0,0), (0,1), (1,1)$). But in the figure posted here it is drawn the  contour plot of the estimated from data joint distribution function (I simulated $(X,Y)|((X,Y)\in C)$). Since this experimental joint pdf is not a constant at the points of $C$, you can see more contours lines, not just one.

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the meaning of the level lines? Actually, what is this a picture of?

Comment: @Did I insert an Edit to explain what the plot represent.

Comment: Then I cannot understand why a nonzero proportion of the points are out of the triangle?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Try the event $C:=\{Y>X\}$. The joint density of $(X,Y)$ conditional on $C$ is uniform on the 'upper triangle' of the unit square, so $Y$ and $X$ are positively correlated given $C$.

Comment: is the reason they are correlated simply that,  $P(X=.25)$ depends on whether $Y\geq .75$? (that is, the probability that $P(X=.25)$ is either 2 or 0 depending on where we are in the triangle (and similar for other points)

Comment: @user106860 Yes. One way to interpret the statement  "$X$ and $Y$ are correlated" is that knowledge of the value of $Y$ affects the distribution of $X$.