# Rewriting $P(X\geq f(Z) \wedge Z\leq z^*)$ using conditional dist. when $X, Z$ are independent

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose we have two random variables, $X$ and $Z$, that have independent density functions (technically they are distributed uniformly  on $[0,1]$, but for this question I don't think it matters)

> **My question is how to write $P(X\geq F(Z) \wedge Z\leq z^*)$ using conditional distribution.**
>
> That is, how can I write a joint density as a a product of marginals (one possibly conditional), when both parts of the joint density depend on the of the R.V.s?

(Assume $F$ is monotonic for simplicity)

Here is an illustration/ elaboration: Suppose that $X,Z$ are independent and I wish to write $P(X\geq 2-Z^2 \wedge Z\leq z^*$ as $P_{X\vert Z\leq z^*} (X\geq 2-Z^2) P(Z\leq z^*)$. Is the $P_{X\vert Z\leq z^*}$ correct, or can I write it as $P_X (X\geq 2-Z^2)$ because of independence?

Also, If i wanted to write $P_{X\vert Z\leq z^*} (X\geq 2-Z^2)$ as an integral, would it be $$1-\int_{\infty}^{z^*} P_{X\vert Z\leq z^*}(x) dx$$ This seems wrong since $z^*$ is part of the event being conditioned on, and is an upper bound (i.e. it feels like I am double counting)

Note: I think my question relates to [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1320904/344247), but here I am actually asking how I would write the joint probability as a product of conditional and marginal (and also how to write as an integral)

Comment: The identity $P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)$ is always correct by definition of conditional probability, provided that $P(B) > 0$. For the integral part, first you abused the notation $P$ being both probability and some function else. If you have confusion, try not to condense the notation. You may start with $\displaystyle \Pr\{X > 2 - Z^2|Z \leq z^*\} = \int^{z^*}_{-\infty} \Pr\{X > 2 - z^2\}f_{Z|Z\leq z^*}(z)dz$ where $f_{Z|Z\leq z^*}$ is the conditional pdf.

Comment: @BGM That integral! Can you point me to a source where I might find a derivation/explanation of that? (or if it is a definition where I can see the definition)  And with regard $P(A\cap B)=P(A\vert B)P(B)$ always being correct... alright. I guess what I am more interested in is whether $P(A\vert B) = P(A)$ in the case of the question (where $A$ and $B$ both depend on $Z$, but $X,Z$ are independent.)

Comment: @BGM, perhaps to be more clear, I think of $X\geq 2-Z^2$ as an event, $X\in (2-Z^2,\infty)$. With that interpretation my (wrong) intuition is that $P(X>2-Z^2\vert Z\leq z^*) = \int_{2-z^2}^\infty f_{X\vert Z\leq z^*}(x\vert Z\leq z^*)dx$, which I get from the definition of $P(X\in A\vert Y=y) = \int _A f_{X\vert Y}(x\vert y)dx$. **Anyway**, my main interests are where that integral you stated comes from, and also independence as I stated in the previous comment and the question

Comment: First the event consist of $X$ and $Z$, so it contains a double integral (2-dimensional / 2 "random sources") rather than a single one. Note that the probability inside the integral is the inner integral. The key of this step is the law of total probability (continuous sense). Once conditional on $Z = z$, the event no longer dependent on $Z \leq z^*$. If you are not confident about this yet, try to write it as a double integral first.